# How to Efficently Test Whether an SQL Server Instance is Running in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, connection

I have an SQL Server (2008 R2) based (C# WinForms) application that predominantly runs on a local machine using a local installation of SQL Server 2008 R2. One problem I have is that if the user does not have a server instance running and tries to execute some commands or perform some operations, the queries are sent off to SQL Server and it takes an age to throw an `SqlException` telling me the requested instance is not started.

I have read the following [question and associated answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979/detecting-if-sql-server-is-running), but these solutions are far from ideal. WMI seem very much over-kill and I do not want to have to include extra .dlls in my installation package for the software if it can be avoided.

I have also come accross the `SqlDataSourceEnumerator` Class documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.aspx)

```
// Retrieve the enumerator instance and then the data.
SqlDataSourceEnumerator instance = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
System.Data.DataTable table = instance.GetDataSources();
```

which dumps the available connection into a `DataTable`. However, there seems to be inherent problems with returning all the available connections:

```
"All of the available servers may or may not be listed. The list can vary depending on 
 factors such as timeouts and network traffic. This can cause the list to be different 
 on two consecutive calls." - MSDN.
```

There has to be a set way of dealing with this problem. Say I have the following `SqlConnection` string:

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout = 0
```

what can I use as an *efficient* (this is crucial) check as to whether the selected instance ('localhost' [the default instance] or 'SomeInstanceName') is running?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you simply try opening a connection to that instance and it does not exist or is not available you should be able to capture the exception and handle accordingly.

Comment: Yes but it can take serveral munutes to come back in some curcumstances! Cheers.

Comment: Take a look at the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287439/some-tricky-quick-way-to-validate-oracle-db-connection/9288048#9288048). It is asking about Oracle but also applies to SQL server.

Comment: Sure, it can take several minutes to come back, if the server isn't running. You can't make a more efficient connection attempt but you can shorten your connection timeout (say, 5 seconds).

Comment: I thought below you answered "I could be wrong but does the connection timeout not also determine how long it waits from the query to run before timing out?" with "No, that is a command timeout"? I was just going to write: If the `Connection Timeout` is set to zero the time taken to throw the `SqlException` telling me there is no running instance is of the order of minutes. For a timeout of ten seconds it is about ten seconds. There must be some correlation here?

Comment: So basically on app load I could run a `SELECT * FROM sys.Tables` on Master with a `Connection Timeout = 1` to check if the relevent instance is indeed operational?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the connection timeout to be a shorter period, but essentially, the only way it knows that a server isn't there, is from a timeout.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to worry about timeouts or network issues when the server and client are the same machine. Just attempting to connect is about efficient as you're going to get, the crucial part is going to be how long do you let the connection attempt try before you give up (connection timeout). You can shorten that window obviously, but if you make it too short, then the problem doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I could be wrong but does the connection timeout not also determine how long it waits from the query to run before timing out?

Answer (score 1):

Any technique you use will likely have the exact same timeout issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the instance name, such as "MSSQL$InstanceName" you can use the System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController class to get a list of all services on the machine and then loop through looking to see if any ServiceName == MSSQL$InstanceName.

I have found this to be very fast plus you can check to see if it is running and start it if it is not running.

Answer (score 0):

You could try opening up a simple TCP connection to the standard SQL port and see if it sticks .
set the connection timeout to some reasonably low value based on your environment.

see

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932

for sql serevr port numbers.